# SQL Server Data has script tags in a Memo Field with Intranet IP Address

Tags: sql-server, coldfusion

We have a ColdFusion page where admins can insert/update some real estate records after logging in. We are noticing that in one table's Memo field called 'description', there are sometimes  tags which hacking/junk info occasionally. I have introduced Captcha. The page is password protected and no linked from any pages--no accessible by search engines unless someone gave out the url accidentally. We are now also tracking the IP address of the person who is doing the inserts/updates. But still we just saw that all the data in the description field had the [junk text] -appended' to the end of the valid text , with an internal ip address of 192.168.0.101. This IP is someone's personal computer. One of our theory is that the person's computer is compromised. But what kind of virus would do that? Also, what I would like to do is to have a field called 'approved' which is 'no' by default but anytime an Insert/Update happens it goes to 'no' and 'triggers' an email to admins about the change. What could be the syntax of that inside SSMS? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely cause is SQL injection. It could be that your internal PC is compromised by malware or a viris that is attacking your site using one of many dozen attacks. The most common of them do exactly what you are describing...append content to the end of text or character fields in the DB. Here's a [description](http://www.coldfusionmuse.com/index.cfm/2008/7/18/Injection-Using-CAST-And-ASCII) of one common attack that does just that.

I would also check the following

- Make sure handler scripts are "locked down" too - not just root urls. Sometimes a script you include is accessible via url and is used in hacking attempts.
- Look for old code elswhere in your site that might not be password protected. if you have a legacy code base chances are there's some old code lying about that needs clean up :)
- Look in the web logs for URL params with values that begin with *EXEC(*  - this is a common approach to injection.
- Scan the PC in question rigorously. Install charles or wireshark and watch HTTP traffic to see what's going on.

Finally, check all your cod for vulnerability to SQLi. Make sure all your variables use cfqueryparam and you have other controls in place. Passwords are not the only level of protection you need :)

Comment: One adendum - you might also look for the words DECLARE and CAST( in the web server logs.

Comment: Hey, thanks. I will try out your suggestions later. I guess I can also figure out an email trigger anytime a way is changed inside the 'description' field.

Comment: Another addition to Mark's excellent suggestion list is to make sure any pages that process incoming data are using scoped variables (FORM.description) instead of "description") and also check that the referer is your own internal form.  Most scripted attacks use "GET" and pass in data as URL variables.  It is possible to spoof referers, but it's just another layer of "make it annoying to try to hack my stuff".

Comment: Ooh, and I forgot a big one!  Never, ever, ever allow errors to dump to the client.  Always catch all of your errors with a CFERROR tag in your application.cfm (or "onError" handler in application.cfc).  Errors are how people get data because they're intended to be helpful to developers who are debugging the issues.